# Can someone explain this disassembly of strlen to me

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, strlen

I disassembled a function that works like strlen:
[image: Click here for picture]

Can someone explain how to works to me? I know it is used to get the length of a string, what I want to know is how it does that.

Also, one thing that has always confused me about assembly is how to variables are stored in the stack. Are they stored by order of declaration (var _8, var _4, arg_0) or the first one last? Are they stored in a crescent way or decrescent way from ebp (refering to the addresses they are stored in)?
I read that they can be stored in a decrescent way, being that ebp has the higher value address and that is called C convention, and then there's the Pascal convention which is the other way around... how do I know which is being used by a program? I'd appreciate if you could address these questions in your explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: Your C vs pascal argument is confusing parameters with local variables. There is no order required for local variables in most languages, but there can be a residual ordering simply because there has to be SOME ordering.

Comment: "a function that works like strlen" so if it is not `strlen` what is it?

Comment: @WeatherVane A function that takes a string and loops through it, incrementing a control variable for each cycle and returning when the '\0' character is reached.

Comment: Well that is how it does it. After `test edx,edx` the green branch goes to termination when the byte read (sign-extended to `edx`) from `ecx` index is `0`.

Comment: You need to read a book on assembly language. That will help you much more than asking one shot questions. I recommend Jeff Duntemann's books on the subject. http://www.duntemann.com/assembly.html

Comment: Calling convention is not necessarily language dependent.  For each compiler (version) for each target, there is a calling convention.  Parameters and return variables, etc are implemented using that calling convention.  One C compiler might do it one way another may do it another.  Same goes for Pascal.  very easy to test for, build a very simple function, disassemble it, and see where it put the variables.  (pass in several variables, add one to the first, two to the second, etc.  add up all those numbers and return that value,  forces the compiler to show you where everything is)

Answer (score 1):

This is a snippet of very poorly optimized assembly language.
It uses local variables in a [stack frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Stack_and_frame_pointers) even though it has plenty of registers at its disposal.

As you can see it uses the [`cdecl` calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) because its single parameter is transferred using the stack.

The function only takes a single parameter: `[arg_0]`: a pointer to a [zero terminated string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)#Null-terminated).
It has two local variables `[var_4]`:the length counter of the string and `[var_8]`:the running [pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) into the string.

The middle block reads the string one byte at a time and test to see if that byte is zero. If so we are done and can return the length.
If not we increase the string pointer in a horribly inefficient way and increases the length counter and jump back to the middle block to test the next byte.

The manipulation of esp `sub esp,8` to create space for local variables is called a stack frame and both Pascal and C (if optimizations are off) will generate a stack frame.
However the Pascal calling convention passes the first 3 parameters in registers (eax, edx, ecx). C uses the `cdecl` calling convention which pushes all parameters on the stack.

When it's done it loads the length into `eax` (functions in all calling conventions always return their result in `eax`).
And it cleans up the stack frame: `mov esp,ebp; pop ebp`
After that it returns to the caller using a near return: `retn`

You can tell local variables and parameters apart because local variables have a negative offset from `ebp` and parameters have a positive offset from `ebp`.

This is the kind of code you get if you forget to turn on optimizations.
Never look at unoptimized assembly code, it teaches you bad habits and will serve to confuse rather than enlighten you.

Comment: There are cases where you should look at unoptimized assembly code, but they're rare: it's only helpful when you're learning about compiler construction.